# AWS load balancing

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

When we define AWS load balancers, we define various components like listeners, rules, conditions, target groups.

A target group contains multiple resources, like EC2 instances. Load balancer maps incoming requests to target groups based on rules and conditions. But as we have multiple instances in a target group, so how is traffic load balanced within a target group.

Do we have to define load balancers for target groups too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS does load balancing for all healthy instances in a target group. The algorithm by default is round robin. You can change Target Group Attribute `load_balancing.algorithm.type` to `round_robin` or `least_outstanding_requests`. See more [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#modify-routing-algorithm)